# ¿Como crear tablas de productos con información del servidor, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.
Debo generar tablas html con listado de productos según la información que venga del servidor.
Básicamente tengo un arreglo `Grupos`el cual contiene los grupos con su listado de productos, dichos listado deben ser mostrador al usuario.

```
    Grupos: [
    {
    CantidadGrupo: 1
    Combinable: 1
    Grupo: 2,
    Texto: "Puedes elegir 1 Producto de esta lista.",
    Productos: [
     {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "32900", Descripcion: "HairX Shampoo Brillo e Hidratación", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "556"},
     {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "8150", Descripcion: "Glacier EdT", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "600"}
    ]
    },
    {
     CantidadGrupo: 1
     Combinable: 1
     Grupo: 2,
     Texto: "Puedes elegir 1 Producto de esta lista.",
     Productos: [
         {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "32900", Descripcion: "HairX Shampoo Brillo e Hidratación", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "556"}
         {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "8150", Descripcion: "Glacier EdT", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "600"}
          ];
       }
    ];
```

De momento he logrado hacer esto:

```
var grupos = $('.grupos');
                        $.each(Grupos, function (index, Grupo){
                            $('<div/>').addClass('list-block no-hairlines no-hairlines-between')
                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('card data-table data-table-init')
                                            .append($('<div/>').addClass('card-header')
                                                    .append($('<div style="font-size: 17px;"/>').addClass('data-table-title').html(Grupo.Texto)))
                                            .append($('<table/>').append($('<thead/>')
                                                                    .append($('<tr/>').append('<td class="nuevo-td">Producto</td><th class="label-cell nuevo-th">Descripcion</th><th class="label-cell nuevo-th">Seleccionar</th>')))
                                                                  .append($('<tbody/>'))))
                            .appendTo(grupos);
                        });
```

Pero no se como mostrar cada registro de productos segun la tabla que le corresponde, recordando que cada grupo tiene su listado de productos en el arreglo `Productos`.

Visualmente me ha quedado de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

hola @JG_GJ lo que no entiendo es por que estas haciendo todo eso en javaScript al vuelo, cuando podrías tener la tabla montada, con las clases ya hechas, luego asignarle el título con el valor del arreglo y por ultimo, rellenar los campos.

el foreach se lo estás indicando mal,te pongo un ejemplo para sacar los valores de los Grupos y de los productos:

```js
var varGrupos =  [
    {
    CantidadGrupo: 1,
    Combinable: 1,
    Grupo: 2,
    Texto: "Puedes elegir 1 Producto de esta lista.",
    Productos: [
     {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "32900", Descripcion: "HairX Shampoo Brillo e Hidratación", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "556"},
     {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "8150", Descripcion: "Glacier EdT", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "600"}
    ]
    },
    {
     CantidadGrupo: 1,
     Combinable: 1,
     Grupo: 2,
     Texto: "Puedes elegir 1 Producto de esta lista.",
     Productos: [
         {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "32900", Descripcion: "HairX Shampoo Brillo e Hidratación", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "556"},
         {IDPedido: 0, Codigo_Inventario: "8150", Descripcion: "Glacier EdT", Tipo: 1, Existencia: "600"}
          ]
       }
    ];
    
    $.each(varGrupos,function(index,value){
            console.log(value.Grupo);
            
        
        $.each(value.Productos,function(i,value2){
            console.log(value2.Descripcion);
        });
        
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```